# Converting String to date in PHP for Date and time like 18 July, 2013 12:00

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, date, datetime

I have **date and time** stored as **string** in following format **"18 July, 2013 12:00"** in mysql database.

I am using wordpress for my website, where this date is **meta_key** of post.

I need them to be converted, from string to date and time.

strtotime() function not working properly with this format. Also I want to saperate month and date.

Also I tried  `echo date( 'format', strtotime("18 July, 2013 12:00")` it gives 01/01/1970 output

Comment: Are they stored as `VARCHAR` in the database?

Comment: What do you mean with "separate month and date"?

Comment: You could use Regex to get all parameters, and replace month-names with the proper number instead, and then convert that new string that you could build from all parts. This could work: `(\d{1,2}) ([a-zA-Z]+), (\d{4}) (\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2})`

Comment: I am using Wordpress. This date is **meta_key** and stored as **char**

Comment: Step 1 - use data MySQL's data types that are meant to store dates. Step 2 - get to know the language you use. PHP has `DateTime` class which can create date time object from an arbitrary format. Step 3 - if you talk to other engineers, provide sufficient data. Step 4 - learn that this isn't "Hi, I can't code, please provide me with stuff" type of website.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why it's not working is because of the format you passed on `STR_TO_DATE()` is invalid. Try this,

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(yourColumn, '%d %M, %Y %H:%s') newDateTime
FROM   tableName
```

but if you want to separate the month and date, the resulting value will be string for month.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT((STR_TO_DATE(yourColumn, '%d %M, %Y %H:%s'), '%M') month,
       DATE(STR_TO_DATE(yourColumn, '%d %M, %Y %H:%s')) dateOnly
FROM   tableName
FROM   tableName
```

Comment: I am using Wordpress. This date is **meta_key** and stored as **char**

Answer (score 0):

```
$raw_date=str_replace(',', '', "18 July 2013 12:00");// Or get it from Database
$month=date('m', strtotime($raw_date));
$date=date('d', strtotime($raw_date));
```

[PHP Date Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php/)

Comment: One might want to be noticed that OP's string contains a comma after MON while this answer doesn't. That seems to be a key different for `strtotime`.

Comment: `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d F, Y H:i');` and wow, we're done in 1 line of code. And then we do black magic like `echo $date->format('d.m.Y');` and it *works*! Black magic I tell you.

Comment: @SuryaS Their is no comma in your example

Comment: @MakarandMane - please don't make statements such as those, you saw several ways to work with the date format you gave, use your head and change things that aren't working, you don't need to be spoon fed.

Comment: @MakarandMane Pardon me. If there is comma or not the solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the comma in the string, it is possible to start a new `DateTime` object.
Take a look at the following example:

```
$string = str_replace(',', '', '18 July 2013 12:00');
$DateTime = new DateTime($string);

print_r($DateTime);
```

This will output :

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2013-07-18 12:00:00
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Amsterdam
)
```

Comment: Or you can use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` which doesn't require you to use str_replace.